# How to translate this list-based code into using mutable arrays?

Tags: arrays, haskell

**EDIT3:** I'm writing a code to process very long input list of `Int`s with only few hundred non-duplicates. I use two auxiliary lists to maintain cumulative partial sums to calculate some accumulator value, the how's and why's are non-important. I want to ditch all lists here and turn it into nice destructive loop, and I don't know how. I don't need the whole code, **just a skeleton code would be great**, were read/write is done to two auxiliary arrays and some end result is returned. What I have right now would run 0.5 hour for the input. I've coded this now in C++, and it runs in 90 seconds for the same input.

---

I can't understand how to do this, at all. This is the list-based code that I have right now:<sup>(but the Map-based code below is clearer)</sup>

```
ins :: (Num b, Ord a) => a -> b -> [(a, b)] -> ([(a, b)], b)
ins n x [] = ( [(n,x)], 0) 
ins n x l@((v, s):t) = 
  case compare n v of
    LT -> ( (n,s+x) : l , s )
    EQ -> ( (n,s+x) : t , if null t then 0 else snd (head t))
    GT -> let (u,z) = ins n x t
          in  ((v,s+x):u,z)
```

This is used in a loop, to process a list of numbers of known length, <sup>(changed it to foldl now)</sup>

```
scanl g (0,([],[])) ns  -- ns :: [Int]
g ::
  (Num t, Ord t, Ord a) =>
  (t, ([(a, t)], [(a, t)])) -> a -> (t, ([(a, t)], [(a, t)])) 
g (c,( a, b)) n = 
    let
      (a2,x) = ins n 1 a
      (b2,y) = if x>0 then ins n x b else (b,0)
      c2     = c + y
    in
      (c2,( a2, b2))
```

This works, but I need to speed it up. In C, I would keep the lists `(a,b)` as arrays; use binary search to find the element with the key just above or equal to `n` (instead of the sequential search used here); and use in-place update to change all the preceding entries.

I'm only really interested in final value. How is this done in Haskell, with mutable arrays?

I tried something, but I really don't know what I'm doing here, and am getting strange and very long error messages (like "can not deduce ... from context ..."):

```
goarr top = runSTArray $ do
  let sz = 10000
  a <- newArray (1,sz) (0,0) :: ST s (STArray s Int (Integer,Integer))
  b <- newArray (1,sz) (0,0) :: ST s (STArray s Int (Integer,Integer))
  let p1 = somefunc 2 -- somefunc :: Integer -> [(Integer, Int)]
  go1 p1 2 0 top a b

go1 p1 i c top a b = 
    if i >= top
     then 
      do
       return c
     else
       go2 p1 i c top a b

go2 p1 i c top a b =
  do
   let p2 = somefunc (i+1)  -- p2 :: [(Integer, Int)]
   let n  = combine p1 p2   -- n :: Int
   -- update arrays and calc new c 
   -- like the "g" function is doing:
   --    (a2,x) = ins n 1 a
   --    (b2,y) = if x>0 then ins n x b else (b,0)
   --    c2     = c + y
   go1 p2 (i+1) c2 top a b  -- a2 b2??
```

This doesn't work at all. I don't even know how to encode loops in do notation. Please help.

**UPD:** the Map based code that runs 3 times slower:

```
ins3 :: (Ord k, Num a) => k -> a -> Map.Map k a -> (Map.Map k a, a)
ins3 n x a | Map.null a = (Map.insert n x a , 0)
ins3 n x a = let (p,q,r) = Map.splitLookup n a in
  case q of 
    Nothing -> (Map.union (Map.map (+x) p) 
                 (Map.insert n (x+leftmost r) r) , leftmost r)
    Just s -> (Map.union (Map.map (+x) p) 
                 (Map.insert n (x+s) r) , leftmost r)

leftmost r | Map.null r = 0
           | otherwise = snd . head $ Map.toList r
```

**UPD2: The error message** is " Could not deduce (Num (STArray s1 i e)) from the context () arising from the literal `0' at filename.hs:417:11"

that's where it says `return c` in `go1` function. Perhaps `c` is expected to be an array, but I want to return the accumulator value that is built while using the two auxiliary arrays.

---

**EDIT3:** I've replaced `scanl` and `(!!)` with `foldl` and `take` as per Chris's advice, and now it runs in constant space with sane empirical complexity and is actually projected to finish in under 0.5 hour - a.o.t. *... 3 days !* I knew about it of course but was so sure GHC optimizes the stuff away for me, *surely it wouldn't make that much of a difference*, I thought! And so felt only mutable arrays could help... Bummer.

Still, C++ does same in 90 sec, and I would very much appreciate help in learning how to code this with mutable arrays, in Haskell.

Comment: This code is really hard to follow.

Comment: the second half is mostly gibberish as I really dont know what I'm doing. The first half is a working code, it just calculates something in a loop, while maintaining two auxiliary lists - which I want to turn into arrays, for speed.

Comment: The _first_ half is still too difficult follow.  Could we get some type signatures, maybe?  Or some comments?

Comment: I endorse Louis' request. On a different note, inserting into a sorted array may not be the most efficient way. Perhaps you can use `Map`s for it?

Comment: with maps it runs 3 times slower, because it not just inserts, but also must update all entries before the insertion point, and so must `union` the updated first half with the second half.

Comment: @DanielFischer  I've inserted type signatures from GHCi.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I've inserted type signatures.

Comment: I would hope that `union` of `Map`s is more efficient than on average if all keys of one are smaller than all keys of the other. So what I'd try would be a combination of `splitLookup`, `Map.map (+x)`, `insert` and `union`. But well, it might be slower. Unrelated, if possible, use monomorphic types. That would get fewer clearer error messages for the mutable arrays.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't even know how to encode loop in `do` notation, and if `do` goes under or above the `if`.

Comment: @DanielFischer with lists there is at least some sharing of tails.

Comment: Yep. And the `Map` code is pretty close to what I'd have tried, so that's a dead end. Could become competitive if you'd be willing to copy most of the `Data.Map` code and write a special `union` for this use case, but ugh. So let's look at arrays. It would still help a lot to know what the functions are supposed to do. It looks like `ins` keeps a list with a cumulative sum in the second components of the elements, but what about the second component of the overall result? If the `GT` branch is never hit, it's the cumulative sum of the tail, but if `GT` is hit, it's no longer, so what's it?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that's cumulative sums from the right, with 0 at the rightmost position. Each invocation of `g` increments the accumulator by a certain amount, calculated for the input integer `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly unorthodox, I am adding a second answer using a mutable technique.  Since user1308992 mentioned Fenwick trees, I have used them to implement the algorithm.  Two `STUArray` are allocated and mutated during the run.  The basic Fenwick tree keeps totals for all smaller indices and the algorithm here needs totals for all larger indices.  This change is handled by the `(sz-x)` subtraction.

```
import Control.Monad.ST(runST,ST)
import Data.Array.ST(STUArray,newArray)
import Data.Array.Base(unsafeRead, unsafeWrite)
import Data.Bits((.&.))
import Debug.Trace(trace)
import Data.List(group,sort)

{-# INLINE lsb #-}
lsb :: Int -> Int
lsb i = (negate i) .&. i

go :: [Int] -> Int
go xs = compute (maximum xs) xs

-- Require "top == maximum xs" and "all (>=0) xs"
compute :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
compute top xs = runST mutating where
  -- Have (sz - (top+1)) > 0 to keep algorithm simple
  sz = top + 2

  -- Reversed Fenwick tree (no bounds checking)
  insert :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
  insert arr x v = loop (sz-x) where
    loop i | i > sz = return ()
           | i <= 0 = error "wtf"
           | otherwise = do
      oldVal <- unsafeRead arr i
      unsafeWrite arr i (oldVal + v)
      loop (i + lsb i)

  getSum :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> ST s Int
  getSum arr x = loop (sz - x) 0 where
     loop i acc | i <= 0 = return acc
                | otherwise = do
       val <- unsafeRead arr i
       loop (i - lsb i) $! acc + val

  ins n x arr = do
    insert arr n x
    getSum arr (succ n)

  mutating :: ST s Int
  mutating = do
    -- Start index from 0 to make unsafeRead, unsafeWrite easy
    a <- newArray (0,sz) 0 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int)
    b <- newArray (0,sz) 0 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int)
    let loop [] c = return c
        loop (n:ns) c = do
          x <- ins n 1 a
          y <- if x > 0
               then 
                 ins n x b
               else
                 return 0
          loop ns $! c + y
    -- Without debugging use the next line
    -- loop xs 0
    -- With debugging use the next five lines
    c <- loop xs 0
    a' <- see a
    b' <- see b
    trace (show (c,(a',b'))) $ do 
    return c

  -- see is only used in debugging
  see arr = do
    let zs = map head . group . sort $ xs
    vs <- sequence [ getSum arr z | z <- zs ]
    let ans = filter (\(a,v) -> v>0) (zip zs vs)
    return ans

up = [1..6]
down = [5,4..1]
see'tests = map go [ up, down, up ++ down, down ++ up ]

main = putStrLn . unlines . map show $ see'tests
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your incredibly generous help! Not only I have a code to study mutable arrays now, but also a clear code for a Fenwick tree! One thing if I may: the input list is very long; your code is not "online" in two places. I can guesstimate the `top` value instead of calling `maximum`; but in `see` you use `xs` to find out all unique keys in the input. This info is available in the first tree, as it counts each incoming key. So all elts of the first tree with non-zero frequencies are exactly the keys that we need to see in the second tree. Thanks again!

Comment: Well. Entries with non-zero keys in a Fenwick tree may not have been inserted directly, the insert may add to several entries.  By computing all the running totals you can detect which ones are bigger than the previous one and this does indicate an inserted key.

Comment: That is what I meant. Individual frequency, not cumulative frequency. Fenwick tree ought to provide for querying of both, both in O(log n) time. I guess it's trivial with `getFrq arr k = do {a<-getSum arr k; b<-getSum arr(k+1); return (b-a)}`, right? Or here in `see` with using `let ans = filter (\(a,v) -> v>0) (zipWith(\(a,v)(b,u)->(a,u-v)) vs (tail vs))` (or is it `->(b,u-v)`?). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Are the input values ever EQ?  If they are not EQ then the way `scanl g (0,([],[])) ns` is used means that the first `[(,)]` array, call it `a` always has `map snd a == reverse [1..length a]` at each stage of `g`.  For example, in a length 10 list the value of `snd (a !! 4)` is going to be `10-4`.  Keeping these reversed index values by mutating the second value of each preceding entry in `a` is quite wasteful.  If you need speed then this is one place to make a better algorithm.

None of this applies to the second `[(,)]` whose purpose is still mysterious to me.  It records all insertions that were not done at the end of `a`, so perhaps it allows one to reconstruct the initial sequence of values.

You said "I'm only really interested in final value."  Do you mean you only care about the last value in list output by the `scanl ..` line?  If so then you need a `foldl` instead of `scanl`.

Edit: I am adding a non-mutable solution using a custom Finger Tree.  It passes my ad hoc testing (at bottom of code):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Data.Monoid
import Data.FingerTree

data Entry a v = E !a !v deriving Show

data ME a v = NoF | F !(Entry a v) deriving Show

instance Num v => Monoid (ME a v) where
  mempty = NoF
  NoF `mappend` k = k
  k `mappend` NoF = k
  (F (E _a1 v1)) `mappend` (F (E a2 v2)) = F (E a2 (v1 + v2))

instance Num v => Measured (ME a v) (Entry a v) where
  measure = F

type M a v = FingerTree (ME a v) (Entry a v)

getV NoF = 0
getV (F (E _a v)) = v

expand :: Num v => M a v -> [(a, v)]
expand m = case viewl m of
             EmptyL -> []
             (E a _v) :< m' -> (a, getV (measure m)) : expand m'

ins :: (Ord a, Num v) => a -> v -> M a v -> (M a v, v)
ins n x m =
  let comp (F (E a _)) = n <= a
      comp NoF = False
      (lo, hi) = split comp m
  in case viewl hi of
       EmptyL -> (lo |> E n x, 0)
       (E v s) :< higher | n < v ->
         (lo >< (E n x <| hi), getV (measure hi))
                         | otherwise ->
         (lo >< (E n (s+x) <| higher), getV (measure higher))

g :: (Num t, Ord t, Ord a) =>
     (t, (M a t, M a t)) -> a -> (t, (M a t, M a t))
g (c, (a, b)) n =
  let (a2, x) = ins n 1 a
      (b2, y) = if x>0 then ins n x b else (b, 0)
  in (c+y, (a2, b2))

go :: (Ord a, Num v, Ord v) => [a] -> (v, ([(a, v)], [(a, v)]))
go ns = let (t, (a, b)) = foldl g (0, (mempty, mempty)) ns
        in (t, (expand a, expand b))

up = [1..6]
down = [5,4..1]
see'tests = map go [ up, down, up ++ down, down ++ up ]

main = putStrLn . unlines . map show $ see'test
```

Comment: yes, of very long input list there only few hundred non-duplicates. The two lists just maintain cumulative partial sums to calculate some accumulator value, the hows and whys are non-important. In C each `ins` operation would be essentially O(1). Yes on a `foldl`, I used `scanl` for debugging purposes. Anyway I want to ditch all lists here and turn it into nice destructive loop, and I don't know how. I don't need the whole code, just a skeleton code would be great, were read/write is done to two auxiliary arrays and some end result is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of `foldl`, it turned projected run time of 3 days to 0.5 hour!! (It would've been enough, yesterday, to run it for 0.5 hour. The irony!). In C++ it takes 90 sec though, and I'd still like to learn how to code this with mutable arrays in Haskell. It not nice to feel ignorant, and I can't make sense of anything on haskellwiki or learnyouahaskell etc. about this. I've updated the Q.

Comment: @user1308992 : The fingertree code I just posted should be O(log n) for `ins` instead of updating O(n) entries each time.

Comment: A. It seems what I have is almost Fenwick tree; I have O(m) update, WP says it should be O(log m), m=number of keys; B. I don't know FingerTree module, it'll take me forever to get all the `|>` and `><`s; I understand the concept, have read apfelmus' blog entry; C. I could easily have O(log n) upd at cost of storing individual frequencies instead of cumulative, but I need the sum to calc the increment on each step. Is there any summing going on deep in the M's guts on each increment in your code? And if not and it is all delayed and stored somewhere, will it create a massive space leak...?

Comment: btw I only need `fst $ go ns`; the two dictionaries just build/pass the info forward as `foldl g` rolls over, so there is no need for `expand` (except in data-debugging).

Comment: @user1308992 C: Yes, there is summing going on in the guts of the figertree.  The internal nodes keep the F monoid added up, so the `measure hi` and `measure higher` ought to be fast.  This is why I am using the FingerTree.  The exclamation marks are too keep things strict enough to not worry about space leaks.

Comment: @user1308992 B: >< is `mappend` or "concatenate".  |> and <| are "append" and "prepend" for elements.  The monoid `F` is keeping track of the sum and the higher element, this allows `split` to do an efficient search.  The sorted ascending contraint is maintained by having no bugs in the `ins` code.

Comment: Thank you very much, will study this. I still can't upvote your answer. As for accepting, I really wanted to see how to program with the mutable arrays. Thank you again for your help. About summing, I have nagging suspicion this would affect complexity since `ins` needs the sums on each step. Fenwick somehow exploits redundancy of adding all *equal* values to the right (here, left) of insertion point I think. To store n `x`s takes O(n); to store one `n*x` takes O(1) (only it goes into *"wrong"* place). He does something in between I guess, very clever stuff. Thanks again!